# How do I run Chromium on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium, vnc

I am running ubuntu server (no gui).

I am trying to run Chromium and somehow view the gui using another tool (vnc?)

When I try to run `chromium-browser` I get this error:

```
(chromium-browser:3869): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I think I might have to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

I really don't know how to do this at all. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a GUI application if you have a headless server without a GUI. In Linux/Ubuntu you need to install XWindows. I expect that when installing Chromium there were some suggestions on installing other dependancies? Like XWindows. Otherwise you could install a mininum GUI like XFCE4 without all the dependancies (so not the Xubuntu desktop, but only XFCE4). This will enable you to start the XWindows system from command line (startxfce4) when you want. But it is no longer a real headless server.

Like the other commenters said: you can start it using ssh -X (-X will forward XWindows) but not VNC. The VNC software expects a GUI already running, while ssh -X will start it's own (have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

When using SSH from a different computer you also need a XWindows server. For windows install CygWin (and XWin) or use XMing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -X server.some.where` and you get `$DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ssh to log in to the server, use the option `-X` for `X11` forwarding. Otherwise, there was some issue with launching Chrome as `root`. You can see it [here](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-41187.html)